# Assigning variables to objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, variables, object

I am using the following method to basically create a JSON string.

```
var saveData = {};
saveData.a = 2;
saveData.c = 1;
```

However the .a and .c don't cut it for what I need to do, I need to replace these with strings. So something like..

```
var name = 'wibble';
saveData.name = 2;
```

This would get accessed with

```
saveData.wibble
```

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var name = "wibble";
saveData[name] = 2;

alert(saveData.wibble);
```

Note that, in JavaScript, the following notations are equivalent:

```
obj.key
obj["key"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the map accessor:

```
var name = 'wibble'
saveData[name] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access Javascript objects using a dictionary notation:

```
var name = 'wibble';
saveData[name] = 2;
```

saveData.wibble is now 2.